# Question about hdr (highest density regions) function

Tags: r

I am seeking help in order to understand the reason why `50%` in this case has 4 different values and what it means. I have seen `hdr` function used in order to calculate credible interval but I want to understand the underlying theory better.

```
library(hdrcde)
set.seed(3)
x = rnorm(100)
hdr(x, h = bw.nrd0(x))
#$$hdr
#$          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#$99% -1.7398509 1.7800070        NA        NA
#$95% -1.4201507 1.5091742        NA        NA
#$50% -0.8039541 0.6226473 0.6884934 0.7054537

#$$mode
#$[1] 0.1205937

#$falpha
#        1%         5%        50% 
#0.05522019 0.13245133 0.34655653
```

`?hdr` gives the following information

> Calculates and plots highest density regions in one dimension
>   including the HDR boxplot.

*PS: I'm also not sure what other tags would be relevant here. Please feel free to suggest or add*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The underlying reason for your problem.

The density function may have several peaks causing multiple regions of highest density (depending on the selected percentage).

This is unlike the underlying normal distribution which has a single peak and monotonous behavior (continuous decrease when going away from the peak).

The hundred points that you selected have a random behavior and may occasionally be somewhat denser in certain regions that are not dense in the the original distribution. The randomly selected points will not reproduce the exact same density function as the density function of the distribution that they are drawn from.

## A graph for illustration.

The below graph (displaying those multiple peaks) may illustrate the situation,'why you get those multiple regions'.

```
hdr.den(x, h = bw.nrd0(x),prob=c(20,50,90))
```

[image: demonstration of hdr function]

---

cited literature by the package documentation:

Hyndman, R.J. (1996) Computing and graphing highest density regions. *American Statistician*, **50**,
120-126.

Samworth, R.J. and Wand, M.P. (2010). Asymptotics and optimal bandwidth selection for highest
density region estimation. The Annals of Statistics, **38**, 1767-1792.

Wand, M.P., Marron, J S., Ruppert, D. (1991) Transformations in density estimation. Journal of the
*American Statistical Association*, **86**, 343-353.

The first of these articles defines what the regions of the hdr function are. It defines the subset (subset of the space, the regions) $R(f_\alpha)$ with density higher than a value $f_\alpha$ such that the chance of finding a the variable in this region is equal or higher than $1-\alpha$. The subset given by hdr is the smallest of such regions.

See also these expressions

```
> hdr <- hdr(x, h = bw.nrd0(x), prob=c(20, 50, 90))
> length(which(x > hdr$hdr[1, 1] & x < hdr$hdr[1, 2]))
[1] 90
> length(which(x > hdr$hdr[2, 1] & x < hdr$hdr[2, 2])) +
  length(which(x > hdr$hdr[2, 3] & x < hdr$hdr[2, 4]))
[1] 50
> length(which(x > hdr$hdr[3, 1] & x < hdr$hdr[3, 2])) + 
  length(which(x > hdr$hdr[3, 3] & x < hdr$hdr[3, 4]))
[1] 20
```

Which means that the regions bound respectively 90, 50 and 20 percent of the points (and they are the smallest for the sum of the size of the regions that do this).